# Save daily data for each year for 4d array

Tags: r, arrays, netcdf4, ncdf4

I have precipitation data and potential evapotranspiration (PET) data for a period of 5 years. I am undertaking a simple calculation of precipitation/PET for each longitude and latitude within an array. I then want to save this daily data for each month of each year to a netcdf file so I can analyse it in a GIS. However, I have tried many different ways but cannot get it to work.

I am trying to use:

```
lats = 712
lons = 584

# Initialize an empty 4D array for daily petvals
  petvals_daily = array(0., c(lons, lats,5,365)) #lons, lats, years, days

#Load climate data
  np=nc_open(paste("TAMSAT_", y, "_regrid.nc", sep=''))  

# open precipitation files

  pet=nc_open(paste("cru_ts4.06.pet.dat_remap_", y, "_01_temp_366_final.nc", sep=''))  

# open PET files
  
  P = ncvar_get(np, 'rfe_filled')
  petvalues = ncvar_get(pet,'pet')

  ts=dim(P)[[3]] #set petvals array coordinates the same as precipitation coordinates
  
  # initialize petvals
  petvals = array(0., c(lons, lats, ts))
  
  # read coordinates 
  LON = ncvar_get(np, 'lon')  # set longitude coordinates to same as .nc file with precipitation data
  LAT = ncvar_get(np, 'lat')  # set latitude coordinates to same as .nc file with precipitation data
  ts=dim(P)[[3]] #set petvals array coordinates the same as precipitation coordinates
    
  
  for (i in 1:lats) { 
    for (j in 1:lons) {
      petvals[j, i, ] = petval(start = ss, end = ee, precip = P[j, i, ], PETv = petvals[j, i, ])
    }
  }

# Save daily petvals for each year
  for (d in 1:365) {
    dlDD = format(daterange, '%d') == DD[d]
  petvals_daily[,,y-1982,d] = petvals[,,dlDD]
  }
```

But this leads to the error:

```
Error in [<-(*tmp*, , , y - 1982, d, value = petvals[, , dlDD]) : subscript out of bounds
```

I have tried to modify the subscript placement as well as the structure but it has not worked..

Comment: What is the dimension of `petvals`?

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for your comment, I edited the above to includes what petvals pertains to. It has dimensions of  `petvals = array(0., c(lons, lats, ts))` , aka 1:584, 1:712, 1:365

Comment: In that case are you like duplicating the data? seems to me that you have petvals with dim `(584,712,365)` and you want to put this data into `petvals_daily` with dim `(584,712,5,365)` does that mean all the years are just a duplication? ie are exactly the same?

Comment: @Onyambu I left out some parts of my code to make it more concise, but basically the code loops over climate data for each year. So basically, it shouldn't duplicate, but for each year of the model it will run the model function using the unique climatic data for each day of each month of each year using a `for (y in 1985:1989) {              ` loop like that. The model uses the data for each year, then loops and loads the data for the next year and runs again. I want to save the outputs of the model each time it runs to the array shaped `(584,712,5,365)`. Hope you're getting me?

Comment: But petvals has no years. It only has daily.  So how can you write the days into years? Or are the daily for just one year?

Comment: If that is the case then you do not need the last for loop ie do `petvals_daily[,,y-1982,] = petvals` This inputs the data accordingly. Note that `y = c(1983,1984,1985,1986,1987)`

Comment: @Onyambu yeah so petvals calculates the values just for the year of climate data that are loaded, and then loops around to recalculate for the next year. I will try your suggestion, thanks for your input and help! I successfully used this code to save monthly data to an array but cant do the same for daily for some reason:

Comment: `for (m in 1:12) { 
    blMM<-format(daterange,'%m')==MM[m]                                                                        
    petvals_monthly[,,y-1982,m]=rowMeans(petvals[,,blMM],na.rm=TRUE,dims=2)` where                                                                             `petvals_monthly=array(0.,c(lons,lats,5,12))` . Was hoping to do similar for daily data for each year..

Comment: This monthy code is seems incorrect. it is not doing what you expect it to do. Note that calling `petvals_monthly[,,y-1982,m]` returns `an array of dim  `lon-lat` and not of dim `month` you are confusing the dimensionality and the way the array is arranged. Note that `lon,lat,year,month` means the rows are lon, the columns are `lat`, the first depth is year and the second depth is `month`. If you do the rowmeans of `petvals[,,i]` you are doing the means across the lats. ie you will end up with means for each longitude, and not for each month. The arrangement might be abit confusing

Comment: Thus `rowMeans(petvals[,,i])` should return a vector of length 712. The code is working because of recycling. But still not correct.

Comment: This would make a lot of sense given my model results - I have been trying to work out why my model outputs over 5 years look like model outputs for just one year. I can't thank you enough for pointing this out! Do you have a suggestion of how I can change it to do row means for each month instead of each latitude?

Comment: Yes, just change the structure of the array. Use `aperm` function to transpose the array accordingly

Answer (score 0):

So I answered based on @Onyambu guidance in the comments:

instead of:

```
# Save daily petvals for each year
  for (d in 1:365) {
    my_years_daily = format(daterange, '%d') == DailyData[d]
  petvals_daily[,,y-1982,d] = petvals[,,my_years_daily]
  }
```

I needed to simply do:

```
petvals_daily[,,,] = petvals
```

Thanks to Onyambu for the guidance!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer. Answered questions are first visited on search. And a few words on petvals[,,y-1982, d] =, i.e. a step through of the loop, updating the array that will be useful to future searchers as summary rather than reviewing comments, which may be sufficient to rename d1DD to my_years_daily...

Comment: Thanks @Chris, have updated and will accept answer. I am new to this! Also, perchance do you know how I can apply a monthly mean to the time dimension of an array that is [i,j,k], where k is daily data for a year? I was using  '# Loop over months`
  `for (m in 1:12) {
    my_months_yearly <- format(daterange, '%m') == MyMonths[m]
    Q0ym[,,y-1982,m] = apply(Q0d, c(2), mean)`  but this is giving the error `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , , y - 1982, m, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  subscript out of bounds`

Comment: Also, it says I can only accept my own answer in two days.

Comment: You have good material for a subsequent question in your above comment, use it there as all of these help others.  And you can edit before you accept.