# How to apply a monthly mean to daily data in a 3d array, storing this to a 4d array?

Tags: r, geospatial, netcdf, ncdf4

I have daily geo-spatial data over a period of 2 years. The data is in two nc files, each containing 365 days' worth of data. I want to apply a calculation to the data, and then calculate the monthly mean of this for each 12 months of each year across each gridbox.

```
lons <- 584
lats <- 712
MyValues_ym <- array(0., c(lons, lats, 2, 12))
MyCalculation <- array(0., c(lons, lats, ts))  ## set up data array to fit dailycalculations 
MyMonths = c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')
ts <- dim(P)[[3]]  ## set MyCalculation array coordinates the same as precipitation coordinates
## Dimension of precipitation coordinates: [584L, 712L, 365L]
```

```
## calculate MeanMonthly  #calculated monthly q0 
## Loop over months
for (m in 1:12) {
  MyValues_ym[, , y - 1982, m] <- apply(MyCalculation, c(2), mean)
}
```

This is giving the error:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , , y - 1982, m, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to use `rowMeans`, but this was not calculating the mean for the time dimension of my array. I am not sure how to calculate the mean for the particular dimension required.

I tried this with RowMeans:

```
    # Loop over months
    for (m in 1:12) {     
    my_months_yearly <- format(daterange, '%m') == MyMonths[m]    
    MyValues_ym[,,y-1982,m]=rowMeans(Q0d[,,my_months_yearly], na.rm = TRUE, dims = 2)
```

**EDIT**

I have now made a MRE:

```
lons <- 10
lats <- 10


MyYearlyMonthlyData <- array(0., c(lons,lats,1,12)) ## set up array for monthly calculation 
MyCalculationYr1 <- array(runif(1:100), c(lons, lats, 365)) ## set up data array to fit dailycalculations 

## set up the date range and months for the loop
start = '1985-01-01'
end = '1985-12-31'
daterange = seq(as.Date(start), as.Date(end), "days")
MyMonths = c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')
y=1985

## the loop to generate monthly values of each day of each month for the year

for (m in 1:12) { 
  blMM <- format(daterange,'%m') == MyMonths[m]
  MyYearlyMonthlyData[,,y-1984,m] = rowMeans(MyCalculationYr1[,,blMM],na.rm=TRUE,dims=2) 
}
```

Comment: Not reproducible, What is `ts`?

Comment: This question evolved from [prior 4D array question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203111/save-daily-data-for-each-year-for-4d-array), and I think `ts` is just to say time series, though informally. And under the rubric of one good error develops one good question...Now to make a MRE.

Comment: @jay.sf apologies, I am new to this so still getting to grips with how to structure these types of questions (thanks for lending me your space bar). In my model it is coded as `ts=dim(P)[[3]] #set MyCalculation array coordinates the same as precipitation coordinates`. As @Chris pointed out, this question came from a previous question. What is an MRE?

Comment: @JonathanTinsley Se there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: BTW, in R, for integers we write `1L` and for doubles `1`, not how you did `1.`.

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf, I have now made a MRE. Hope this might help make helping me a little easier. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Chris, do you think it would be worth me deleting this question and making a new one with the MRE?

Comment: Can you please describe P? Is this a file of precipitation observations or predictions? What is its source? Your solution should probably use a factor of months which you then `apply(P, 1:2, tapply, f, mean)`. My guess is that you should take a few steps back rather then fix what you have now.

Comment: Hey @Patrick P is an array of precipitation variables from a netcdf file of observational precipitation data for a year. It is sourced from TAMSAT. I am applying climatic data to climate-parasite transmission model. The model performs the calculations, and then stores them in an array as shown in the MRE.

Comment: Is the original 584/712, MRE 10/10 lons, lat meant to express a ground truth(ed) TAMSAT estimate of a point rain gauge? Just a question on data, not mechanics of executing above that I follow with interest.

Comment: Hi @Chris, the data within the grid represents a TAMSAT estimate of gridded daily rainfall based on satellite data and ground observations :) It is much easier to perform the monthly calculation in CDO (Climate Data Operators) using cygwin (if you are a windows user like myself). e.g. `cdo -L -setattribute,rfe_filled@units="mm/d" -divdpm -monsum TAMSAT.2016.nc TAMSAT.2016.Month.nc1`. I was just interested in knowing if I can do this in R automatically so that I do not need to then go into CDO and perform the calculation. It doesn't take very long in CDO though so will just do that.

Comment: I should add the grid is usually much larger for TAMSAT, I masked the data for the southern Africa region and regridded the resolution to 0.05 degrees (all using CDO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precipitation data is from the TAMSAT archive (as per your comment under your post). I quickly downloaded a file and it conforms to the CF Metadata Conventions, as is common for meteorological data distributed through NetCDF files. You can check that easily by checking for the "Conventions" global attribute:

```
nc <- nc_open("./rfe_file.nc")
ncatt_get(nc, "")$Conventions
```

These files typically contain 3-d arrays of data, as is the case here. Dimensions are `lon`, `lat` and `time`. You can easily work with the `time` dimension using the [CFtime package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=CFtime):

```
library(CFtime)

# Create a CFtime instance from the "time" dimension in your file
cf <- CFtime(nc$dim$time$units, nc$dim$time$calendar, nc$dime$time$vals)

# Create a factor over the months in your data file
mon <- CFfactor(cf, "month")

# Extract the data from the file
data <- ncvar_get(nc, "ref_filled")

# Aggregate to monthly mean (mm/day)
pr <- apply(data, 1:2, tapply, mon, mean)

# Re-arrange the dimension after tapply() mixed them up
pr <- aperm(pr, c(2, 3, 1))

# Label the dimensions
dimnames(pr) <- list(nc$dim$lon$vals, nc$dim$lat$vals, levels(mon))
nc_close(nc)
```

Note that you will now have a 3-d array with the 3rd dimension having 24 elements with labels such as "2021-01", "2021-02" ... "2022-12". The `apply()` function applied the function `tapply()` over the first two dimensions, with `tapply()` applying the `mean()` function using the factor `mon`, so in the result every grid cell has the monthly mean values for the two years.

Comment: And would we be correct to assume your are `CFtime` package author? `vignette('CFtime', package = 'CFtime')` very useful read.

Comment: @Chris Guilty as charged and thanks for the nice words. I am in the process of submitting a new version with more functionality on working with the factors and expanded documentation, including a second vignette! Should be up on CRAN in a week or two.

Comment: Will update then and recommend `CFtime` (when not x:y'd on underlying data source) as this solves many issues that were well past my array imaginings.

Comment: Thank you @Patrick, really useful answer and nice work on the package you've made! Note this can also be achieved in Climate Data Operators (CDO) (using cygwin if you are a windows user) - `cdo -L -setattribute,rfe_filled@units="mm/d" -divdpm -monsum TAMSAT.2016.nc TAMSAT.2016.Month.nc1`. CDO is far superior for manipulating .nc files than R I find. I wanted a way for my model in R to automatically perform the calculation - your answer gives me a good basis to continue with, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @JonathanTinsley. CDO is a very nice set of tools but command-line processing is not for everyone. In R, one big advantage is that you have access to many more tools, such as statistical analyses and plotting with `ggplot2` etc. The above code can be put into a function which would give you a similar one-line experience but certainly here on SO spelling out the work flow serves a higher purpose than reducing keystrokes - see you final sentence as a fine example.